# My Dell showed Missing Operating System

Tags: windows-7

My DELL INSPIRON showed "Missing Operating System" two times since I replaced my laptop with a new hard drive(this about 4-5 months back). Well when I tried restarting it was ok. But Now am frustrated that this will at any time end in disaster where I would finally lose all my files. What would be the reason anyway?

Comment: Have you backed up your personal files?  Its not clear.  Why have you replaced the HDD so many times.  Mosts HDDs have a 2-3 year lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

If this has only happened twice in the last two months, then it is nothing to worry about.  Sometimes there is a glitch in the boot sequence that causes this.

If for some reason, you weren't able to get past the error on restart, you can use [Windows Statup Repair](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/startup-repair) to fix the problem.